# NoMethodError in Admin#index , undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting 'NoMethodError'
Please suggest on how to resolve this issue

Thanks a lot,

```
NoMethodError in Admin#index 
.....
.....
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
.....
.....
Extracted source (around line #23): 

20:     <% for reservation in reservations %>
21:         <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %> ">
22:         <td class="list_description"> 
23:             <dt><%= link_to reservation.machine.name, reservation.machine %></dt>
24:         </td>
25:         <td> <%= reservation.startdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")  %> </td>
26:         <td> <%= reservation.enddate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")  %> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<% if reservation.machine.present?  %>
  <td class="list_description"> 
    <dt><%= link_to reservation.machine.name, reservation.machine %></dt>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: All, Thanks a lot . It worked . Thank you very much Dipak Panchal.

Answer (score 0):

Error occur because of the `reservation.machine.name`. In your case `reservation.machine` for one or more of the reservation returns `nil` and then your are calling `name` method on it.

Best way to avoid such error check before if the objects returns nil or not.

```
<td class="list_description"> 
  <dt>
    <% if reservation.machine %>
      <%= link_to reservation.machine.name, reservation.machine %>
    <% end %>
  </dt>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your reservation controller

```
def index
 @reservation = Reservation.all
end
```

In your view

```
<%= form_for(@reservation) do |r|%>
 <% if r.machine %>
  <%= link_to r.machine.name, r.machine %>
 <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO previous responses are valid in case machine is an optional attribute of the reservation. If it's mandatory you should check the belongs_to relationship in your model.